# im trying to make a file thing but line 8 and line 10 don't seam to match up

Tags: python, file

```
for i in range(100):
    inventory = ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",]
    a = input("--> ")
    if a == "inventory":
        print(inventory)

    elif a == "add-item":
        d = input("item-number--> ")
        gus = input("item-name-->")
        inventory.insert(d, gus)
        print(inventory)
    elif a == "terminate-item":
        c = input("terminate--> ")
        inventory.remove(c)
    else:
        print("no")
```

Comment: Every time through the loop you're resetting the inventory. The `inventory = [...]` line should be before the loop.

Comment: Why are you initializing inventory to lots of empty strings? Why not an empty list, and use `append()` to add a new item to it?

Comment: This code has nothing to do with files.

Comment: thank you i needed help and you fixed it good job.